# Querying view where key is an array and first value matches anything

Tags: couchdb

I have a view that emits keys as such: `[doc.category, doc.country, doc.state, doc.city]`

This works fine as long as I choose a specific category. However, I would also like to sometimes search for any category. What I've tried is using for example these parameters:

```
startkey=[0, "United States", "New York", "Albany"]&endkey=[{},"United States", "New York","Albany\ufff0"]
```

But that returns every document in that view. I also tried re-arranging the keys, but sometimes I still want to allow the first key to be anything.

Comment: You should probably just make another view that leaves out the `category` from the emit. Order is everything when it comes to querying the view, so you can't just exclude the earlier keys.

Comment: Alternatively you could also have multiple emits per document, e.g. also emit `['_all', doc.country, doc.state, doc.city]` for each doc (or no category at all if country never collides). Then query with `startkey=["_all", "United States", ]...`.

Comment: Thanks @oliverdm, I like that solution - although it is unfortunate that it doubles the memory used.